# Unable to login to mysql server by using default username and password i.e root and null respectively

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I am logging in mysql server phpMyAdmin via using default username i.e "root" and password set as default "" but I am unable to login.
It would be great to know the viable solutions to solve this issue. I am logging in via wamp server.

Comment: There is no default password.  And the username is "root" not "roots".  You should've setup a password when installing.

Answer (score 0):

The default username and password is:

username: root

password:

i.e. "root" instead of "roots", and no password.

also if you are inputting the quotes that is incorrect

Comment: Thanks for the comment, yes I am putting root and leaving the password option, still unable to connect.
Although previously I have been logging in by using same username and password.

Also I have checked my config.inc.php file. Do I need to edit some setting there?


config.inc.php file says:
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'Local Databases';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;